# How to tell the office manager in a most possible kind way that I won't check company's WC basin holes for my fallen hair?

Tags: communication, company-culture, cleanliness

Office manager saw my hair in basin in WC. It accidentally felt inside and has been partly washed away while I was washing my hands. She contacted me by Skype and asked to clean it in the future. Now I'm confused what to tell her.

Circumstances: our company has started to rent an entire floor, so all the WCs there are in their responsibility now. They didn't hire a cleaning company or person and don't plan to. Only office kitchen gets cleaned once a several months. Other office rooms hasn't been cleaned for a year so far.

Although I agree we should keep office clean, I feel strong revulsion at being forced to dig into the basins each time I wash hands. There is no equipment or disinfectant liquids to perform such manipulations, not even spare paper (company bought electronic hand drier to save money on that and everything else). I can't stop my hair falling even though I comb it regularly. My responsibility, which is written in office regulations and I agree with, is to keep my desk clean. I don't mind because I'm the only one using it.

I'm usually not conflicting person, but this goes overboard in my opinion. I'm planning to disagree with her. The problem is I'm a bit socially awkward, our Office manager tends to be unprofessional with the stuff. She is often rude and talkative while I'm shy and can't find proper words to answer on time. So I haven't been able to come up with some lines besides "Should I clean the carpets too? My hair is also falling while I'm walking, I bring soil from the outside as well". We are somehow on good terms (but not so good to blatantly tell her this).

Other women' hair also occurs there (we are just 5 females in IT company beside this manager), they leave coffee/tea and other lumps in basins. But I can't simply approach and ask them "What would you tell her in my situation?", because other employees are arguing aggresively and openly (I can't choose this option) with her or ignoring completely.

Am I right thinking like that? What other people do with their falling hair? How to tell her I won't clean the basins in a most professional way?

Update.

> May I ask how much hair you shed and what your bathroom looks like?
>   I'm a guy, so once in a blue moon there is a single hair in the
>   restroom's basin that I just wash down. If my manager told me to not
>   leave single hairs, I'd probably either laugh or nod and ignore him.

It were 2 strings of my hair inside the sink's hole almost washed down but wrapped around litter others leave.

Bathroom... is completely dirty. I hate coming there, but have no other choice. All my proposals are ignored, the company doesn't bother with cleaning. It wasn't a problem while we didn't have company's WCs (and it was also a mess).

I do clean after myself. But I'm on a verge of vomitting just thinking of doing it after others. I work in separate, just mine, office room and I clean my desk and stuff every week. Also, after reading SE, I got myself one spare mouse "for guests".

Beside the dirtiness, it's a very good company and people. Right now I just can't afford leaving. At least for several months. And I am really pessimistic about it...

Comment: So she's basically paying you IT wage for cleaning service. I believe that telling her that would appear like you are trying to do your job for her, so either try to convince her somehow to hire cleaning service(after all, WCs need to be maintained by someone, don't they?), or do as she says.

Comment: May I ask how much hair you shed and what your bathroom looks like? I'm a guy, so once in a blue moon there is a single hair in the restroom's basin that I just wash down. If my manager told me to not leave single hairs, I'd probably either laugh or nod and ignore him.

Comment: @nvoigt 2. But I'm the only 1 with a red hair here, so she knows they are mine.

Comment: @bolov They save money on everything, but pay us much. I have flexible hours and other perks as well. My colleagues... they are just untidy and don't cooperate.

Comment: In what country are you ? If you're in western coutrnies they're problably laws that force the company to garantee a decent hygiene of your working environment

Comment: @Walfrat Eastern Europe. Yes, we have laws (on paper), but it's near impossible to enforce them.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how much hair you lose and what "digging" in the basins means.  I would expect that asking people to leave the WC in at least the same condition as you found it in upon entering to be a normal request.

Comment: @NotMe literally 2. I didn't even see them, because they were almost in the sewerage, in the hole. She was taking out the other garbage and found them.

Comment: Most employees make more money per hour than a cleaner would make, and a professional cleaner will do the job quicker and better than most employees would. So I think the company is acting unwise making their employees do the cleaning.

Comment: @gnasher729 +1. That should be the answer. The OP should answer "I try to keep the bathroom as clean as when I come in. However, this cannot always be achieved. The company should hire a professional cleaner. It is much more efficient and will be cheaper to the company than making us clean ourselves each and every hair."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how this will work. Your manager and maybe the owners have decided that the staff is going to be responsible for cleaning the bathroom. However, they don't want to assign it to be the responsibility of anyone in particular because everyone will balk because that's not the job that you all were hired for.  So the strategy is to find one person on the team who they can induce to feel guilty about the bathroom stuff, and that guilty feeling person will pick up the task from that point out. So you are being tested to see if you are that weak link. And your office mates are being tested too, it's just that you're not seeing that part.

Do clean up what **you** might leave in the sink, and if your manager ever speaks to you about cleaning up the entire space without offering you some more money, simply smile and ignore her.  Don't commit to anything because you'll become the *de facto* cleaning-lady. Or in any such conversation ask, "are we also talking about more pay?"  She will leave you alone real quick.

Comment: I always clean after myself, but those 2 hairs were in the basin hole. She was taking out other litter (she cleans coffee machine's cup here) and found them wrapped in it. And I'm in no way will put my hands on this mess. And if I tell about more pay part she will just get furious. Though I'll try it if she persists. Looks like there is no easy way...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if this might appear patronising, but there's a couple of practical measures you might want to try.

1. Put the plug in the sink while you brush your hair.  Removing said hair would then be a lot easier and less messy
2. Stand further away from the sink while brushing your hair

Comment: 1. We don't have such thing. 2. I don't comb it near the sink. I washed my hands only.

Comment: Ok, sorry for my misunderstanding.  Here in the UK, we normally have a way of closing the sinks.